# You need to use a different package name because "com.caspianz.hayatkhan.flashlight" is already used by one of your other applications

Tags: android, android-studio

I have unpublished one of my app in Google play console and now I want to upload the same app with changed name (Previous name flashlight) (new name FlashTorch) but it gives me this error {You need to use a different package name because "com.caspianz.hayatkhan.flashlight" is already used by one of your other applications.}. I have changed my Computer name from Hayatkhan, can that be the problem for this error.[changed package name snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZmsE.png) also changed ApplicationId to the new package name (FlashTorch) in Build.gridle. need your kind suggestion plz

Answer (score 1):

Have you changed package name inside Gradle (app config)

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.gsm.com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Already changed that not for once but Three times but still give me the uploading error. I upgraded my Android studio to 3.2.1 if that could be the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to gradle file:

[image]

and change this line:
[image]

I noticed that you want to upload an app to the play store, please note that every app in the store has its own package.
You will also be unable to install more than one app with the same package name on your own device

Comment: Already changed that . test in your case not the whole package name but still give me the uploading error. I upgraded my Android studio to 3.2.1 if that could be the reason ?

Comment: change the package name, build the gradle again (switch between two implementation lines and click on the top message bar to try build gradle again). after that create new APK file and upload it..

Comment: Still not working bro. tried every thing you mentioned but not happening

Comment: You have another applications in your console at store?

Comment: yes I Have other application but they are with different package name. I have copied description from the unpublished app and past in the description of the new app. will that can be the problem ?